# Connection Timeout -- Is AWS having issues?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I setup a simple ec2 ubuntu instance to host my teamspeak server.

Today the server shutdown (which has happened before) So I tried to ssh into the instance. I kept getting connection timeout (which was not making sense, never had this problem before)

I created a brand new instance, and was able to connect with putty into the public Ip for about 2 minutes, and then putty crashes as I am setting up the server.

After putty crashes, I get the connection timeout error again and I cannot reconnect unless I stop the instance completely and start it again. (I can then connect again but after 2 minutes I get the timeout error)

Does anybody have some insight into what is going on?

Also, my security settings are now set to be completely open and I am still unable to connect

Comment: have you asked Amazon's AWS support at all? they can better check and see what is wrong than we can without access to it. I use AWS and this kind of behavior generally seems to be a usage issue, where you might be hitting up against a limit you have set, intentionally or not, that is basically kicking in to ensure you don't go over a set limit. You might also want to review your settings, specifically your Cloudwatch and Alarms, the logs should tell you what is going on.

Comment: I am in free tier usage. It is at 0% usage for everything.
I sent a ticket to amazon, but I don't even have the ability to use tech support since I am in free usage.

Comment: Free tier does have support but you might have to wait a bit longer to get a response. One of my students had an issue where their card, which is required to be on file for any "overages" was not valid. Can you go to your AWS console, log in using your "root" credentials, not IAM user, go to the billing dashboard, scroll down to the alerts and notifications area, do you see anything there blaring at you?

Comment: What do you mean by "putty crashes" when you are connected?

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ the free tier only offers support for *account*-related issues, not technical support.  In a case like this, technical support would almost certainly observe -- correctly -- that the infrastructure is fine and user action or software running on the instance is the trigger for the problem.  Just as it would rarely be appropriate to call the gas supply company when your recipe does not turn out successfully in your gas oven, AWS support is generally limited to the infrastructure, not your application of it.  Infrastructure problems across multiple instances should be particularly rare.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot while I appreciate your colorfully inapplicable and grossly incompatible comparisons, you would be wrong. While they don't support application related issues as part of the support, they do access the logs which go beyond your observation of ~ all is fine ~ and if they observe an interaction with the infrastructure that is not consistent with how it should work, yes they do take action beyond blowing you off. I am not sure of the extent of your experience with them, but leave room for the possibility that you don't know everything like you might think you do. Anyway it's moot.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ I didn't intend to imply that AWS support would blow someone off.  Quite the contrary, the point is that they would almost certainly not find a problem because it is overwhelmingly likely that there is no problem in the infrastructure to find, or, in the case of a failed or impaired host system, the solution they offer will be something one should have already tried -- stop/start to attach to new hardware.  The infrastructure should be the last component suspected, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this error :
[image]

follow all the steps given below : **We have to make SSH accessible from anywhere from inbound rules.**

***step 1*** : choose your running instatnce.

[image]

**step 2** : click on enlarge button

[image]

**step 3** : Click on the security groups

[image]

**step 4** : Click on the edit inbound rules and after that choose source to anywhere of SSH

[image]

**step 5** : Save your rules

[image]

***Now try to open your putty. Hope you find it useful :)***